# tortoisehg hangs on update after using rebase + strip on multiple branches

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

First things first, I'm a total moron for even being in this position at all. Newish dev with < 2 years experience and not a lot of time with version control, much less hg and tortoisehg.

I wanted to revert a merge, so after several failed attempts to create a new branch from my last good commit and merge it back into my local branch, I discovered the rebase extension could strip back to a good commit. (That said, since I had already pushed my bad commit, it didn't really solve my problems).

I went ahead used rebase > strip a few times nevertheless, and now tortoisehg hangs whenever I try to update.

hg cli still works, it's just tortoisehg that I seem to have broken. Tried uninstall/reinstall of tortoise, no luck.

I find that other guys in the office can pull and update without problems, so it's strictly a local problem.

Any suggestions on how to restore functionality? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran another uninstall using ccleaner, and then did a search for anything related to tortoise in my C:/ drive. Renamed every entry I could find (mostly in AppData/Roaming) and then reinstalled thg. Successfully updates and does everything else as usual now.